Postgres / Spring Boot authentication issue
I have basic CRUD with Spring Boot and when I try to call the API from postman I always get error 401 which is an error related to credentials not being correct. But I'm sure about my credential. I'm also sure that the error is not from my code cause I tested this code before with a Postgres database and it did work.
Here is the application.properties
spring.application.name=users
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/resto
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
debug=true


logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

logging.level.org.springframework.data.jpa=DEBUG

I tried creating the database again and creating a new user(testuser) in pg admin and I granted all the privileges for this user and table and I even tried creating a database with the testuser being the owner.
These are the logs after adding
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

2024-08-24T20:54:35.426+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@7ea8224b
2024-08-24T20:54:35.426+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-08-24T20:54:35.426+01:00  INFO 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-08-24T20:54:35.438+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user/find
2024-08-24T20:54:35.443+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-08-24T20:54:35.473+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/user/find?continue to session
2024-08-24T20:54:35.475+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2024-08-24T20:54:35.475+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2024-08-24T20:54:35.475+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@2e590e36
2024-08-24T20:54:35.475+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2024-08-24T20:54:35.475+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@1554e681
2024-08-24T20:54:35.479+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-08-24T20:54:35.479+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-08-24T20:54:35.480+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session
2024-08-24T20:54:35.480+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2024-08-24T20:54:35.480+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@257d3968, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2024-08-24T20:54:35.480+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@2e590e36
2024-08-24T20:54:35.480+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2024-08-24T20:54:35.480+01:00 DEBUG 25524 --- [users] [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@1554e681


first of all let get some info to what actually the problem is.  Set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG so that you see the error. After that paste the error into question

Also show what endpoint are you calling and how (copy the call from postman as cURL command and add it to the question). Also show your security configuration

im calling this endpoint GET http://localhost:8080/user/find

i did not create any security configuration class

I would advise against using the admin username and password in your app.   Better to create an app-specific ID and database and restrict access just to the tables intended for the for the app.

When you add spring-security dependency but do not define any security configuration then the default security configuration is applied that looks like this:
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(UserDetailsService.class)
InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() { 
    String generatedPassword = // ...;
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(User.withUsername("user")
                .password(generatedPassword).roles("USER").build());
}

basically it creates a default user with username user and with password that is printed to console at startup. Will look like this:
Using default security password: 78fa095d-3f4c-48b1-ad50-e24c31d5cf35

Alternatively you can define username and password in your application.properties:
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin

Both of these options are for local development only. In production you should define a proper Spring configuration with username and password (encrypted) stored in database for example
Once you know your username and password you can use them with Basic authorization (there is basic authorizaiton option in postman)
If you are using cURL you can do:
curl -u user:password http://localhost:8080/user/find


In general you should either configure your own security configuration or remove spring-security if you don't need it

i tried setting the user name and password and adding the basic authorization in postman and it is working now thank you so much for your help
